# Pandas: How to delete rows based on some conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I've a table:

|  | Number | B | Action | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 161 | False | send: | 2021-10-20 13:10:18 |
| 2 | 202 | False | get | 2021-10-20 13:10:20 |
| 3 | 202 | False | take | 2021-10-20 13:10:21 |
| 4 | 161 | False | reply | 2021-10-20 13:12:25 |
| 5 | 202 | True | send | 2021-10-20 13:15:18 |
| 6 | 161 | False | get | 2021-10-20 13:15:20 |
| 7 | 161 | False | take | 2021-10-20 13:15:21 |
| 8 | 202 | False | reply | 2021-10-20 13:15:25 |

Here, True/False is based on whether column 'Action' has 'send' without colon or not. If 'send' then it's True, otherwise False.

I want to delete rows based on condition of a row which is True. So, delete rows if:
i) a column 'Number' has a same a number which corresponds to value True in column 'B', In this case: delete if Number== 202
ii)and if a column 'Datetime' is in range of 2 minutes of a column which corresponds to value True in column 'B'. Datetime corresponding to True value is '2021-10-20 13:15:18' and it's range of 2 is: [2021-10-20 13:13:18 ; 2021-10-20 13:17:18].

Overall, deleted rows should have a number=202 and which are in range [2021-10-20 13:13:18;2021-10-20 13:17:18]

New table should look like this:

|  | Number | B | Action | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 161 | False | send: | 2021-10-20 13:10:18 |
| 2 | 202 | False | get | 2021-10-20 13:10:20 |
| 3 | 202 | False | take | 2021-10-20 13:10:21 |
| 4 | 161 | False | reply | 2021-10-20 13:12:25 |
| 6 | 161 | False | get | 2021-10-20 13:15:20 |
| 7 | 161 | False | take | 2021-10-20 13:15:21 |

Sorry, if a question and task is not fully clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`df = df.loc[df["Number"]!=202 & df["B"]!= 'True']`

If type in column B is boolean, then change the string "true" to a boolean True.

Comment: I have over 100k data, so I don't know which Number corresponds to True value. Also there might be many True values. Firstly, I'll create new column 'B', which is True if in column 'action', string 'send' has no colon, False otherwise.